# Faulty solution for K&R exercise 1-19

Tags: c, arrays, function

Context: I have experience in JAVA programming so perhaps that is what's stopping me from understanding the issue. Exercise 1-19 asks to write a function reverse(s) that reverses the character strung s. Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time.

Note: I have slightly modified the input parameter to also take the length of the character array.

This solution is faulty, as shown below.

Function : (YES and NO are constants of values 1 and 0 respectively)

```
void reverse(char input[],int lim)
{
    char tmp[lim];
    int j , nl_check;
    nl_check = NO;

    for(j=0; j<lim-1 && input[j]!='\0';++j) {
        if(input[j] == '\n') {
            nl_check = YES ;
            break;
        }
    }

    --j;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=j ; ++i) {
        tmp[j-i]=input[i];
    }

    if(nl_check==YES) {
        tmp[++i]='\n';
    }
    tmp[++i] = '\0';

    for(i=0; tmp[i]!='\0';++i) {
        input[i] = tmp[i];
    }
    tmp[++i] = '\0';
}
```

The input :

```
$cat example
hello
this
is
me
and
code
```

The output :

```
     $./a.out < example > output; cat output


    olleh
    sihth
    sih
    h
    emh
    h
    dna


    edoc

    edoc
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with making a character array inside the function, as when I reversed it without creating a new char array inside (the better way clearly), it worked well. However, I still don't understand what the issue with this code is...

EDIT : Below is a working function that does not use the creation of an array, implying that the '/n', '/0' was not the error.

```
    /* Similar to @DNT suggestion, I believe.. this function works.*/
    void reverse(char input[] , int lim)
{
    int j , nl_check;
    nl_check = NO;
    for(j=0; j<lim-1 && input[j]!='\0'; ++j)
    {
    if(input[j] == '\n')
    {
        nl_check = YES ;
        break;
    }
    }

    int i,z;
    char tmp='\0';
    --j;
    for(i=0,z=j; i!=((j+1)/2) ; ++i,--z)
    {
    tmp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[z];
        input[z] = tmp;
    }
    if(nl_check==YES)
    {
    input[++j]='\n';
    }
    input[++j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: You are calling `printf("%s",tmp);` before writing anything to the `tmp` array. I don't see how this would work in Java either.

Comment: `printf("%s",tmp);` prints `tmp` before the function has assigned any values to its elements. Why is that line there? At best, it prints data left on the stack from previous calls to the function.

Comment: The `tmp[++i]='\n';` and the first `tmp[++i]='\0'` can overrun the end of `tmp`.

Comment: The second `tmp[++i]='\0';` is not needed and may overrun the end of `tmp`. Perhaps the intent was to put a null in `input` rather than `tmp`.

Comment: Oh huge apologies the printf("%s",tmp) was my attempt at debugging not a part of my program...

Comment: You could break it into two functions, one extracting one line and the other reversing it. 
Each function will then be responsible for one job only. Reverse can also perform its function within the same array that was passed in without copying to a temp by setting an index to `0` on the line, another to `size-1` and iterating up to `size/2` from both sides, swapping values in each loop iteration.

Comment: @MikeJalfrezi: now you don't have a `printf` at all. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, I have done that as well, in another code.. I completely agree that the solution you have provided is the best complexity wise as well of course. However, I'm unable to find the issue in this code. (I have edited it and removed the printf function to show that the issue still persists)

Comment: @Groo yeah I have just updated the code to remove the printf as that was not the core issue of my error. Apologies for not conveying my problem in the right manner.

Comment: Oh wait @Eric Postpischil I think I understand the issue. You say that 'At best, it prints data left on the stack from previous calls to the function' ... so even though my array is within the function reverse, tmp does not get continuously reinitialized right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char a[], int sz)
{
    int k, i,j;
    for (i = 0, j = sz-1; i< sz/2; ++i, --j)
    {
        k = a[j];
        a[j] = a[i];
        a[i] = k;
    }
};

int main() {
  char x[] = "abcdefg\nsecond line\nthird line";
  char *p = strtok(x, "\n");
  while(p)
  {
    reverse(p, strlen(p));
    printf("%s\n", p);
    p = strtok(NULL, "\n");
  }
}
```

With a slight modification, it can ignore newlines and reverse it as a single string.

Your function tests for a newline then reverses only the first string and returns.
If there is only one string with no newlines or one newline at the end, it will reverse it, however as soon as a `\n` is encountered, it stops there. 
A modification to your code should include a loop within your function that checks whether you reached the end of the string or not, and repeat what it does if not.

It is a lot easier, cleaner and good coding practice to break it into two functions, each doing one job only.

Here is another version that is a simplification of your function that does it all in one go:

```
void reverse(char input[] , int lim)
{
    int i, j, z, start=0;

    for(i=0; start< lim ; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '\n' || input[i] == '\0')
        {
            for (j=start, z = i-1; j< start+(i-start+1)/2; j++, z--)
            {
                char tmp = input[j];
                input[j] = input[z];
                input[z] = tmp;
            }
            start = i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is a similar if not the same logic as my alternate reverse function.. It's just that I do not know why my first function is erroneous.

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer and does not explain what is wrong with the original code.

Comment: @MikeJalfrezi It has logic errors. It does not continue past the first line that ends in `\n`. You check for newline only once at the beginning, but then after processing the first line, you do not loop to check the string for more.